# Oracle SQL - How can I find all of possible position of wanted string without specific occurrence

Tags: sql, oracle

As we know that  INSTR() with return a result only one number
Ex. "Harry Potter"
If we use  INSTR("Harry Potter"," ") to find a position of space, we will get '6' from this function right?. But if I want to know all possible of spaces position, how can I modify this condition ( or using another function would be fine)

Ex.  Column name 'Movies' contains name of movies that can be any number of space between word like
  "The Lord Of The Ring", "Age Of Ultron", ......

How can I find all position of spaces and assume that we don't know all of data before so we can't fix an occurrence of space in that column.

```
             Thanks guys,
```

Comment: What is the purpose? What would you do than with spaces? You can write PL/SQL code which do INSTR() in loop and return all spaces positions as Array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (movies) as
  2    (select 'The Lord Of The Ring' from dual union all
  3     select 'Age Of ultron' from dual
  4    )
  5  select movies,
  6         instr(movies, ' ', 1, column_value) space_position
  7  from test,
  8       table(cast(multiset(select level
  9                           from dual
 10                           connect by level <= regexp_count(movies, ' ')
 11                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 12  order by movies, space_position;

MOVIES               SPACE_POSITION
-------------------- --------------
Age Of ultron                     4
Age Of ultron                     7
The Lord Of The Ring              4
The Lord Of The Ring              9
The Lord Of The Ring             12
The Lord Of The Ring             16

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create varray type, which contains numbers. Than create non-default function to get all the spaces. You must have proper privileges.

```
-- SOLUTION

-- create varray type
-- it contains max 20 numeric elements
create or replace type array_n is varray(20) of number;

-- this function gets string and returns array of numbers
-- numbers show spaces in the text
create or replace function getspaces(fname varchar2) return array_n  is
    arr array_n; -- arr variable is array_n type
begin
    -- check, if the text length is longet than 0 (if text is not null)
    if length(fname) is null then return null;
    end if;

    arr := array_n(); -- itialize varray

    -- iterate for each letter in text
    for i in 1..length(fname) loop
        -- if leter is space, extend array and save it's position
        if substr(fname,i,i+1) = ' ' then
            arr.extend; -- Extend it
            arr(arr.count + 1) := i;
        end if;
    end loop;

    return arr; -- return array
end;
/

-- TEST ON SYNTHETIC DATA
create table films (
    id integer constraint film_id primary key,
    name varchar2(30)
);
insert into films values(1, 'The Lord of the Boats');
insert into films values(2, 'All Possible solutions');
insert into films values(3, 'I love you guys');
insert into films values(4, null);


select f.*, getspaces(f.name) from films f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way pretty much the same concept as Littlefoot

```
 WITH a AS 
 (
 SELECT 'The Lord Of The RingAge Of Ultron' as n from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is a movie name' from dual
 )
,b as (
SELECT a.* ,length(n)-length(replace(n,' ','')) o
FROM a
  ) 
 , c as (
 Select distinct  b.*
 ,level le
  from b connect by level < o
order by n
   )
 Select n
 , instr(n,' ',1,le ) occur
  from c
```